# Scrolling using Magic Mouse sometime not work if I don't use the mouse for a few minutes

Tags: safari, mouse

I've just bought a Magic Mouse 2 and there's one thing I'm not sure it's an issue or not. When I read or watch something on Safari, it means I don't use the mouse for about 1-2 minutes, after that I swipe up/down to scroll, it will not scroll until I continue to swipe 1-2 times or move the mouse a little bit.

I'm not sure this is an issue or it's a default behavior of the Magic Mouse. Can I somehow fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This, I'm afraid, is the default behaviour for all modern battery-powered mice, not just Apple's.*

To save power they sleep after a very short period of inactivity & need to be woken again before they'll respond.
Empirically, I've noticed that mouse movement achieves this faster than any more advanced movement such as scrolling.

I see no workaround, other than abandoning wireless mice & returning to wired.

*Obviously, I haven't tested *every mouse in the world* but we have an assortment of Apple & Logitech devices here, all of which exhibit this behaviour.

Comment: that's interesting, thanks for the explanation!